# Synonym [amazon-kms] - [aws-kms]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon these two tags ([amazon-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kms) and [aws-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms)) while looking for other `KMS`-related tags. They seem to both point to the same thing which is the [Key Management System service provided by Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/). They even have the exact same Usage guide:

> AWS Key Management Service (KMS) is an encryption and key management service scaled for the cloud. KMS keys and functionality are used by other AWS services, and you can use them to protect data in your own applications that use AWS.

No one voted for them to be synonyms. The tags don't have many Qs yet (43 Open for the former, 155 for the latter, and 12 apply both) as this is a fairly emerging technology (both tags created around 3 years ago). 3 usernames feature on both lists for Top Answerers, All Time.

I think they should at least be tagged synonyms or be merged.

I have no clue whether a synonym or a merge is better and which one is the main one, hence this discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The synonym for [aws-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms) <- [amazon-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kms) was already proposed on Jan 30 at 16:32, but it didn't gather much support as there were not many users who had the qualifications to support the synonym.

I've now approved the proposal and they're now synonyms. I've kept [aws-kms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-kms) as the master, as the service is branded as [AWS Key Management Service](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/kms/).